# Хранение двоичной строки в postgres

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Мне нужно хранить двоичную строку - 24 четверки (0011, 0000 и т.д.). В документации postgres про тип bit(n) сказано, что:

> Для хранения битовой строки используется по 1 байту для каждой группы из 8 бит, плюс 5 или 8 байт дополнительно в зависимости от длины строки

Значит, если я запишу свою строку кратно 8(например 3 поля по 8), то на один символ будет выделяться один бит? И можно ли вообще так хранить, что бы на один двоичный символ выделялся один бит? Как максимально сэкономить память? Спасибо.

Comment: Храни как `bytea`. 24 группы по 4 бита - это 12 байтов, плюс один байт длины, 13 байт на одно поле одной записи. Компактнее хранить в одном поле - не получится. Не, можно поделить на три BIGINT - но заморочки со знаком... а UNSIGNED у постгресса как-то не прижилось.

Comment: Спасибо, а bit чем плох?

Comment: Да оверхед больше. Минимум 5 лишних байтов против одного у bytea. А у тебя компактный размер хранения обозначен как приоритет. У bit по сравнению с bytea есть только одно преимущество - наличие встроенных битовых операций... ну так никто же не мешает bytea приводить к bit для обработки.